# Realm Android Nested Query

Tags: android, realm

Given the below classes and relationships, I need a **RealmResults < Model1 >** that satisfies the following requirements:

**Model1**

```
int id
RealmList<Model2>
```

**Model2**

```
int id
int model1Fk
int type
RealmList<Model3>
```

**Model3**

```
int model2Fk
```

I want to query all the Model1 entities that, for a specific Model2 related instance type, that Model2 instance has at least one Model3 related instance.

In SQL that would be (Haven't tested it):

```
select distinct model1.*
from Model1 model1 join Model2 model2 on model2.model1Fk = model1.id join Model3 model3 on model3.model2Fk = model2.id
where model2.type = 'Some Type'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these models stored in a SQLite database in Android or are they plain Java objects?

If they are native objects, then you could have a reference to those directly.
e.g.

```
class Model1 {
   int id;
   RealmList<Model2> list;
}
class Model2 {
   int id;
   int type;
   Model1 parent;

}
```

You could even build a hashmap that will do all this for you. Depending on how these objects exist in Android one can come up with a strategy.

Comment: They are stored in a Realm (https://realm.io/) instance. I have posted the SQL query for a better understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your text description and join doesn't match, but if you want to find all `Model1` with a `Model2` of `Some type`, you can do the following:

```
realm.where(Model1.class).equalTo("model2List.type", "Some Type").findAll();
```

You can read about link queries here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries.

If you want to find all `Model1` which have at least 1 `Model2` that also have at least one `Model3` with some value, you can do the following:

```
realm.where(Model1.class).equalTo("model2List.Model3List.model2Fk", "some model2Fk value").findAll();
```

Comment: Hi Christian, maybe my confusing english made the question not understandable. Partially what you suggest is okay, however the Model3 relation is still missing from the query. Continuing your query, for those Model1 entities that has a Model2 with the type you have specified, I want the ones which that Model2 has a non-empty list of Model3 entities related. It would be something similar to: realm.where(Model1.class).not().isEmpty("model2List.type[Some type].model3List").findAll();
I know I cannot add parameters to the fieldName in the isEmpty method, it's just to give an example.

Comment: I updated with an example showing how to query for the `Model3` value instead.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior, can you look into this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052965/realm-returns-empty-list-of-object