# Realm returns empty list of object

Tags: java, android, realm

I want to fetch CropDataList from Farmer Object. when i fetch Farmer Object it's not null, but the cropData list associated with Farmer Object returns empty. I can see database entry via Stetho and there list has one entry. Here's my code.

```
public class Farmer extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private RealmList<CropData> cropData;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public RealmList<CropData> getCropData() {
        return cropData;
    }

    public void setCropData(RealmList<CropData> cropData) {
        this.cropData = cropData;
    }

    public static class Constants {
        public static final String FARMER_ID = "id";
    }
}
```

This is my CropData.class

```
public class CropData extends RealmObject {

    private String cropName;
    private String crop;
    private Float cropAcres;
    private Float cropYield;
    private Float cropPrice;

    public String getCropName() {
        return cropName;
    }

    public void setCropName(String cropName) {
        this.cropName = cropName;
    }

    public String getCrop() {
        return crop;
    }

    public void setCrop(String crop) {
        this.crop = crop;
    }

    public Float getCropAcres() {
        return cropAcres;
    }

    public void setCropAcres(Float cropAcres) {
        this.cropAcres = cropAcres;
    }

    public Float getCropYield() {
        return cropYield;
    }

    public void setCropYield(Float cropYield) {
        this.cropYield = cropYield;
    }

    public Float getCropPrice() {
        return cropPrice;
    }

    public void setCropPrice(Float cropPrice) {
        this.cropPrice = cropPrice;
    }
}
```

The list is empty when i try to fetch it via :

```
    HashMap<String, String> credentials = QueryUtils.getCredentials( realm );
    Farmer farmer = realm.where( Farmer.class ).equalTo( Farmer.Constants.FARMER_ID, credentials.get( "farmerId" ) ).findFirst();
    // this farmer is not null, but associated cropData is empty...
    if (farmer != null) {
        RealmList<CropData> farmerCropData = farmer.getCropData();
        **// this list is empty...**
        Log.d( TAG, "getCropList: " + GsonUtils.toGson( farmerCropData ) );
```

this is how i am inserting cropData.

```
public void updateCrop(String authToken, String farmerId, CropDataUpdateRequest cropDataUpdateRequest, Context context) {
        EndPoints.updateCrop( authToken, farmerId, cropDataUpdateRequest, new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<BasicResponse> call, @NotNull Response<BasicResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    BasicResponse basicResponse = response.body();
                    assert basicResponse != null;
                    ErrorCode errorCode = basicResponse.getErrorCode();
                    if (!NetworkErrorHandlingUtils.ErrorCheck( errorCode )) {
                        UpdateCropResponse updateCropResponse = GsonUtils.fromGson( basicResponse.getResponse(), UpdateCropResponse.class );
                        try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {

                            //  update verification Response...
                            realm.executeTransactionAsync( realm1 -> realm1.insertOrUpdate( updateCropResponse.getUpdatedCrop() ) );

                            GetComparisonSheetRequest getComparisonSheetRequest = new GetComparisonSheetRequest();
                            CropData cropData = updateCropResponse.getUpdatedCrop().get( 0 );
                            if (cropData != null) {
                                getComparisonSheetRequest.setCrop( Crop.valueOf( cropData.getCrop() ) );
                            }
                            getIncomeComparisonSheet( authToken, farmerId, getComparisonSheetRequest, context );
                            getYieldComparisonSheet( authToken, farmerId, getComparisonSheetRequest, context );
                            getRecommendation( authToken, farmerId, context );

                            IntentUtils.PassIntent( context, HomeScreenActivity.class );
                            ((Activity) context).finish();
                        }
                    } else {
                        //  show error dialog here..., the error could be from one of the Error Code...

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<BasicResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                //  show UI for API Failure...
                if (t instanceof NoConnectivityException) {
                    //  This is where it throws No Internet connectivity error...
                    //  show some UI here, sefu...
                    IntentUtils.PassIntent( context, NetworkErrorActivity.class );
                }
                //  there's some other error, not network connectivity issue...
                else {

                }
            }
        } );
    }
```

Comment: ok ... and? I don't see any code where you set the value, so why should I assume there is one? have you debugged your code?

Comment: @Stultuske, i am not posting that code here, because i dont want to make you go through hazzle in that aspect. it inserts data. i can verify it via stetho.

Comment: sure. and have you verified the data is inserted to the right instance? have you verified the insertion is done before the get? are you sure that findFirst will get you the instance you're actually looking for?

Comment: Yes, it's giving me the farmer Object which is not null, and via that i am accessing cropdataList, but it's empty. And yes data is inserted before i query it.

Comment: I wasn't asking whether the farmer object is null or not. that's a whole different matter.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, List<CropData> is associated with Farmer, so i can query them, but in my case it's not working. i even provided primary key as well to my Farmer as well.

Comment: add your code for saving data into realm?

Comment: @Avi Patel, insertion of object in realm is the mistake. check  this link https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#writes

Comment: @Stultuske added how i am adding my data.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have find out my answer, I have changed my code as following. I am fetching my list, then clear it and then I am adding new data into that list and updating my farmer Object.

```java
RealmList<CropData> cropDataRealmList = new RealmList<>();
cropDataRealmList.addAll( updateCropResponse.getUpdatedCrop() );

Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();

Farmer farmer = realm.where( Farmer.class )
    .equalTo( Farmer.Constants.FARMER_ID, farmerId )
    .findFirst();

if (farmer != null) {

    RealmList<CropData> farmerCropData = farmer.getCropData();
    farmerCropData.clear();
    farmerCropData.addAll( cropDataRealmList );

    CropData cropData = updateCropResponse.getUpdatedCrop().get( 0 );
    if (cropData != null) {
        GetComparisonSheetRequest getComparisonSheetRequest = new GetComparisonSheetRequest();
        getComparisonSheetRequest.setCrop( Crop.valueOf( cropData.getCrop() ) );

        getIncomeComparisonSheet( authToken, farmerId, getComparisonSheetRequest, context );
        getYieldComparisonSheet( authToken, farmerId, getComparisonSheetRequest, context );
        getRecommendation( authToken, farmerId, context );
    }
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate( farmer );
    realm.commitTransaction();
    realm.close();
    IntentUtils.PassIntent( context, HomeScreenActivity.class );
    ((Activity) context).finish();
}
```

Comment: So if `farmer == null`, you leave the realm instance open? That could cause problems later.